# Split a string into separate words

Tags: text-formatting

I can print a string using echo in bash shell-like `echo "This is a sample string"`.

Is there some command I can use as a pipe or some arguments to echo after the string that could result in the following output:

```
This
is
a
sample
string
```

Basically split the string and print the words each in a new line

Comment: `line="This is a sample string"; for word in $line ; do echo $word; done`

Comment: What have you tried. `awk`, `tr`, `sed` can all do this. If you really just need a constant string, `echo -e "This\nis\na\nsample\nstring"` avoids an external process and a pipeline.

Comment: @Bodo could there be a way to do it without using the line variable and pipe the result of echo?

Comment: @Bodo  Special characters seriously break this. For instance, if the string contains `*`, the output contains a list of all the files in your current directory.

Comment: Please add more details to your question: In which form do you have the string? What characters can occur in the words?

Answer (score 0):

Paul's comment was to the point, needed to avoid filename globbing, my test for the number of arguments left was too simple, and I'm using the Korn shell.

```
V="This is a sample * string"
set -f
set $V
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  echo $1
  shift
done
```

Comment: In Bash, that gives me an infinite number of blank lines after the output. If the text contains `*`, it gives me a list of all files in the current directory, and then an infinite number of blank lines.

Comment: I never use Bash, you just gave me another reason.

Comment: `set -- $V` is probably safer

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "This is a * sample string" | tr ' ' '\n'
This
is
a
*
sample
string
$
```

Answer (score 0):

More of the same

```
s="This is a sample * string"
set -f
printf "%s\n" $s
```

Comment: Probably also need to save and restore initial state of -f flag, or run the whole thing in a subshell. But we still don't know whether the data is coming on stdout (as per the `echo` in the OP, which might be a placeholder for some unknown command), or is in a variable.